# Which command could be used to clear screen in CLISP?

Tags: lisp, clisp

Such as cls for cmd.exe. It's very annoy if I can't do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `screen:clear-window` to do this:

```
(screen:with-window (screen:clear-window screen:*window*))
```

For more information see the documentation on [screen](http://clisp.sourceforge.net/impnotes/screen.html). Also note that these functions are specific to clisp.

Answer (score 5):

That didn't work for me but this did (acquired from the link)

```
(screen:clear-window (screen:make-window))
```

Comment: I'm using clisp on a Mac and this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

**if you are running clisp inside emacs**

```
C-c M-o
```

*which of course is*

```
Control-C Alt-o  -or-
Control-C Meta-o
```

this is the default keybinding to call "clear buffer" from the "repl" menu.

Comment: That is not an appropriate answer because it does not programmatically clear the screen from within the lisp/clisp code.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what terminal you're using(support for ANSI control sequences, for example on most *nix), you could try:

```
(defun cls()
  (format t "~A[H~@*~A[J" #\escape))
```

Then call it:

```
(cls)
```

Answer (score 1):

CLISP UNDER WINDOWS

(ext:run-shell-command "cls")

(defun cls () 
    (ext:run-shell-command "cls") )

then write in the repl

(cls) and voila

Comment: Can you please also add explanation how this resolves the issue?

Answer (score -2):

(loop for x from 1 to 1400
do  (princ "     ")
)

Comment: Of course you can change the 1400 to any number which most suits you

Answer (score -3):

Nilambar this is for clisp 2.49 running under windows

When you are learning like me make a lot of test, try, error, abort etc and screen of repl or interpreter its a pigsty of that trys and its difficult to beginer to found the results to new trys then you type (ext:run-shell-comand "cls") and the repl clean it screen and the prompt go to upper left corner.

Comment: Hello Sai. You are answering the comment in another answer. Please edit your first answer or use the answer comments to give more information.